# Setup Logserver with ELK in AWS EC2 and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, logstash

I have some doubts about setting up an ELK stack on AWS.

1. What are the main difference in setting up an ELK on AWS and Local server?
   (I have already done in my local server)
2. I think ELK stack should setup on EC2 (Correct me if not) In that case can we store logs in AWS S3? How ?
3. How to configure kibana to view logs in AWS S3 ?
4. In my local server , I used Nginx proxy . Is it possible to use Nginx in AWS also?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I can't think of any.  ELK can spread across serveral machines if you like.  AWS would make this easier but there is stuff like security groups to consider.
2. see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-s3.html
3. once the data is in the elasticsearch layer kibana can see it
4. yes

Comment: I am stuck with kibana configuration.
port 5601 is not listening . 
In kibana.yml file I put

server.port: 5601
server.host: "127.0.0.1" Here I also checked with localhost and aws private ip address.
I didn't setup firewall.
Kibana version : 4.4.x